# how to show console app window hidden by createprocess function

Tags: c++, c++builder

I have a GUI in c++. The GUI used to start another independent console based application using `CreateProcess` method. I am hiding these console apps by passing `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag in `CreateProcess`. Now I want to make it visible again. How do I do that?

Comment: You can't.  You had one shot at getting the window created and you passed it up.  The process itself will have to call AllocConsole().

Comment: thanks for reply. If i can't then how do i implement this kind of functionality. I want that, there should be two button SHOW and HIDE, that will show and hide console App window created by CreateProcess. For this i am currently holding PROCESS_INFORMATION..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag, use the `wShowWindow` member of the `STARTUPINFO` struct instead.  Set it to `SW_HIDE` initially (and set the `dwFlags` member to `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW`), then you can use `ShowWindow()` to show/hide the console window when needed.  To find the window that belongs to the new process, use `EnumWindows()` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to find the window whose process/thread IDs match the IDs that `CreateProcess()` returns in the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` struct.

Comment: Thank you friend... I have used this method to get Window Handle HWND. But when i use this HWND to show "mspaint.exe" window in WINDOWS 7 it come up with 3 windows on taskbar, first one is mspaint.exe which does not respond to any click on it, second is GDI+ window which is blank having titled with GDI+ and third is totally blank and does not have any title which too does not respond.. please give any reliable solution....

Answer (score 1):

You had one shot at getting the window created and you passed it up. Thats right but you can show or hide gui, after createProcess method.

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
STARTUPINFO si;
ZeroMemory(&si,sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi);
si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.lpTitle ="my_process_console";
CreateProcess(null,"my.exe",null,null,false,CREATE_NEW__CONSOLE,null,null,&si,&pi);
```

I created process.Now I use find method and then I can show GUI.

```
HWND console_name =FindWindow(null,"my_process_console");
if(console_name){
  ShowWindow(console_name,SW_SHOW);
}
```